# Windows 7 : How to force a program to display on main screen?

Tags: windows-7

Every time a open a certain program on my computer, I can see it visually move/expand to above the viewing area on my screen (so it IS opening). However, I cannot get it onto the viewable portion of my laptop screen.

- There is no external display connected. Nor is one set in display settings.
- The program shows on the task bar.
- When doing: alt+tab or windows+tab, the mini-view of the program looks 100% correct, and is fully displayed (but mini of course)
- I've tried right clicking the task bar and cascading/stacking windows, and it still isnt visible
- There is no 'move' option visible on the taskbar, like in some older tutorials on how to do this
- The computer has been restarted regularly
- The program is otherwise working as it should

Are there any other ways to force a program on screen?

I'm an IT guy and consider myself fairly knowledgable with computers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hold down the Windows key on your keyboard, and press the Left or Right arrow.  This should move the focused window to the left or right side of the monitor.

BTW, if you have multiple monitors, also holding down Shift will move the focused window between monitors.

Comment: Thats the ONLY thing that has worked!! I'm suprised i didn't think of doing that, since i use that function all the time. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried moving it via **shift + win + arrow right/left**?

Comment: I dont think thats doing anything, since the maximize animation still opens it towards the same top/middle section of my screen. I don't think that is working for my other programs either... unless I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: This should move the focused window from one monitor to another. 
Try not holding the shift key - then it should just dock it to a side.
As described here: http://lifehacker.com/5526025/make-the-most-of-your-multiple-monitors-in-windows-7

Comment: Ok, yeah, thats basically what the other person said. Thank you. :)

Answer (score -1):

For my Win 7, programs cannot be moved from Monitor 1 to Monitor 2 unless their view is reduced (the middle position of -, 2 squares, X).  Once the program is reduced in view, it can be dragged over to Monitor 2.

Comment: This would require there to be two screens, the question explicitly mentions there are no external screens attached to the laptop.